# Best practice for iterating over an ad-hoc list of strings in C#

Tags: c#, foreach

When you need to iterate over a hardcoded, ad-hoc/temporary (only used in the foreach) list of strings, what's a best practice or a better coding standard: using a `List<string>` or `string[]`? It's not an array vs List question, but a very specific code situation.

Example:

```
foreach (var item in new List<string>() {"A", "B", "C", ..., "Z"}) { ... }
```

vs

```
foreach (var item in new []{"A", "B", "C", ... "Z"}) { ... }
```

Comment: Define "ad hoc" (*I assume that is what you meant and not "ad-host"*). Are you hard coding these strings? Are you build them from external sources? Are you changing them at a later point in time?

Comment: Best practice would be to use data structure which corresponds to your needed operations. E. g. if you need to insert/remove your data, you should use a `List<string>`. Iteration speed for <100 items shouldn't be an important factor.

Comment: Corrected the typo and added clarifications. The string items are only necessary in the foreach and they are hardcoded

Comment: Based on your updated question: You won't notice a difference either way.

Comment: performance considerations? No. Go with whatever seems more readable to you.

Comment: I think the question might be more relevant for a "coding standard" discussion rather than performance. I updated the question

Comment: This is somewhat opinion-based although I see no reason for using a List in this case. An array is more concise, performant and readable.

Comment: You can follow generic rule to use more restricted interface which in many case can be considered as a good coding standard but again there can be caveats and exceptions depending on specific requirements.

Comment: Why downvotes? The question is perfectly valid.

Comment: Performance-wise arrays are a little bit faster as the compiler optimizes foreach loops over arrays by omitting the iterator/enumerator pattern (which would do a method call for each element) it would normally use and instead directly accesses the array indices. But like others have said this is negligible and has no noticeable realworld impact in your case.